# Number of equations vs number of unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

I was recently brushing up on basic linear algebra and it seemed to be that a lot can be summarised by the following statement:

> Let *m* denote the number of linearly independent equations and $n$
>   denote the number of variables.
>
> 1. If $m > n$, the system has no solution.
> 2. If $m = n$, the system has exactly one solution.
> 3. If $m < n$, the system has an infinite number of solutions.

Is the situation really as simple as this? The reason I ask is that I couldn't see anything quite this simple when I had a brief look just now (although I may well have overlooked it). Instead, I found lots of discussion of determinants, matrices, etc. which seemed fine but a little harder to grasp than the statement above.

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:** It might be sensible to define 'linearly independent'. A sensible definition (i.e. one that seems to make the statement true) is that two equations and linearly independent if and only if neither equation can be derived from the other using linear operations (addition and multiplication by a non-zero constant).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the assumption "there are $m$ linearly independent equations" makes this formulation a little less immediately *useful*, as you then have to go away and check somehow that they are linearly independent (which you do with matrices, determinants, etc). Also if they are linearly independent then $m > n$ is a contradiction so the first point is not so interesting.

Comment: Consider $x=1,x=2$ which are two linearly independent equations in a single unknown.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah whoops, I'd read it as "the coefficients in the variables are linearly independent", as with your interpretation $x + y =0$, $x + y = 1$ is an independent system with $n = m$ but no solution. Either way something is fishy about the statement.

Comment: You are right indeed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust re your example: here there are two linearly independent equations but one unknown ($m > n$), and indeed the system has no solution. I'm struggling a bit to see the point of the example -- perhaps you could help me?

Comment: @afreelunch It was a response to my claim that "$m > n$ is a contradiction", which isn't true if you take the constants into account when you're determining linear independence - but if that's how you define linear independence, my example shows that your claim 2. is incorrect.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I'm afraid I still don't understand your answer. Are you saying that the statement in question is correct (but somehow 'uninteresting' or 'unhelpful'). Or is it incorrect?

Comment: @afreelunch To be clear, if you define equations to be linearly independent if you cannot obtain the coefficients involved in any equation by combining the others, then $m > n$ is not possible (because of some stuff with vectors and matrices), but the rest of your statements are correct. This is the presumption on which I wrote my answer, although what my answer is really trying to say is that your statements aren't very useful. If you define independence as you have retroactively, then your second and third statements are not correct, by my $x + y$ examples.